# How to restore a variable value from memory in an ipython session?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, ipython

How would you restore a python variable from memory once it's been overwritten?

Maybe this makes things a little easier. I'm currently in an ipython session like:

```
In [1]: var = method_that_cant_be_reproduced()

In [2]: var = [4, 5, 6]
```

Would it be possible to restore the values assigned to `var` in step 1, somehow? I'm assuming it hasn't been garbage collected.

I also know some details about the previous value. It was a list and I know its size.

Comment: I overwrote the variable by mistake and it turns out I really need the original contents and they can't be regenerated. And yes, I'm expecting an answer involving some memory inspection black magic or maybe a hidden ipython feature :)

Comment: @NickA possibly, I'm just wondering if someone would have a trick that I could use. As I mentioned in the question, I'm assuming it has not been garbage collected yet :)

Comment: Might not work, but initial tests are showing me that I can recall a value simply by using `locals()` in the console. It's showing me the function calls _and_ the returned value of the function call

Comment: If you hadn't done the initial `var=...`, the result would still be archived in the `Out[1]` list.

Answer (score 3):

When you used `var = [4, 5, 6]` the name `var` was rebound to a new object (the list) and the original object was lost (as there aren't any names referencing it anymore). Because there's nothing left referencing your original object the answer to your question is almost certainly ***no***.

While this may not be the answer that you wanted there are several things to learn from this:

- In the event that a function can only be run once/variable can only be generated once, *don't overwrite it*, keep track of it somewhere be it in another variable or a file
- Try not to be in the situation that a variable can only be generated once (what if your generation procedure has a problem and the source is lost?), *make a copy of your source before consuming it*
- *Anticipate the unexpected*, what if your computer had crashed and your IPython session was lost? Had you stored your result anywhere?

So you've made a mistake, you can still learn from this and move on knowing you won't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation "the result of input line 4 is available either as Out[4] or as _4".

More details [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/tutorial.html#use-the-output-cache).

Comment: There was no output in either of those two lines though. Also, it is a feature of iPhyhon only, not of Python in general. I guess one could parse `In[1]`... but that's pretty much a definition of overkill. tl;dr: save your vars if you think you'll need them.

Comment: Hello, I think it's fine if the answer is particular to ipython (as this is explicit in the question title). But yeah, _1 only stores the output. I'm interested in the actual contents of the variable.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. Actually, you can access the Input Cache as well, see [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/tutorial.html#input-cache). So you can access `In[1]`, which in your case will be a string `"var = [1, 2, 3]
"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @lorenzotenti. But unfortunately it's not that simple. I've updated the example to be closer to reality.

Answer (score -3):

I like to pickle them for retrieval later - especially when I have a class instance or something that takes a long time to recreate when I'm using it for testing.

```
import pickle

with open('pickled_var', 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump('asdf', picklefile)    

with open('pickled_var', 'rb') as picklefile:
    unpickled_var = pickle.load(picklefile)

print(unpickled_var)
asdf
```

in your case, you could pickle it when it's the values you want, and then just load over the "bad" variable to get back to a "good" state.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is asking how to access a value that's been accidentally overwritten. And if you still have access to the value, there's no need to pickle it - just store it in a variable and don't overwrite it.

Comment: If you're trying new things with a variable and aren't sure if what you're going to do to it will break things, you can pickle it and load it.  I do this often with larger datasets that I'm doing manipulation on or designing new modifications around because I don't want to wait 20+ minutes to retrace my steps in creating the original variable, etc.  It does require intermediate steps and taking the time to assess when you're in a good state, but it's a valid way to restore to a known good state if you've mucked things up.